# Bootstrap 4 columns overlapping when resizing screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using a 4 column row within a 3 column container. When I reduce the screen or display it on an iPhone, the text file overlaps with the column containing an image.

See code and screen capture below...

```
<div class="container pl-0 pr-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 pl-0 pr-0"><p>
So if you want to try your hand of Japanese, you will need some dedication. <br>
<br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"><a href="https://vidalingua.com/japanese-english-translator-iphone-ipad">
      <img src="https://vidalingua.com/images/en-jp-translator-thumbnail" 
      style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" width="200"></a></div>
    <div class="col-3 pl-0 pr-0"><p>
Learning Japanese is a lot easier with a great app. <b>Japanese Translator&nbsp;+</b> provides you with quality translations on the go. Download it for free on your <a href="https://vidalingua.com/japanese-english-translator-iphone-ipad">iPhone</a> or <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vidalingua.japanese.dictionary.translator">Android</a>&nbsp;<br>
<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
  </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screen capture...

[image: See below for a screen capture.]

Answer (score 0):

To make your take shift to the next line below the image, you can use `col-12` on the `div` that contains your text.

To make it responsive to different screen sizes, you can add `col-sm-3`, `col-md-3`, `col-lg-3`, and `col-xl-3` so it will be on the right side of the image on the bigger screens.

Here is the documentation about [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/)

Here is an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container pl-0 pr-0">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10 pl-0 pr-0"><p>
So if you want to try your hand of Japanese, you will need some dedication. <br>
<br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-3"><a href="https://vidalingua.com/japanese-english-translator-iphone-ipad">
      <img src="https://vidalingua.com/images/en-jp-translator-thumbnail" 
      style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" width="200"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-12 pl-0 pr-0"><p>
Learning Japanese is a lot easier with a great app. <b>Japanese Translator&nbsp;+</b> provides you with quality translations on the go. Download it for free on your <a href="https://vidalingua.com/japanese-english-translator-iphone-ipad">iPhone</a> or <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vidalingua.japanese.dictionary.translator">Android</a>&nbsp;<br>
<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
  </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```